# Can I sell my MIT-licensed software if it is modified by others?

Tags: derivative-works, mit, monetization

Suppose I create some software from scratch. I sell the software, but I also keep it open source under the MIT License. Someone forks my repository and makes some great improvements to my software. Can I then clone their repository, and sell the improved software without sharing any profits?

Comment: I would humbly suggest that the OP should consider changing to the Apache 2 license as derived works must ship with the same license http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN

Comment: @simbo1905 No? Are you thinking of the GPL license?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Depending on how they chose to provide their fork, yes.

The MIT license, which you chose to license your work under, doesn't prevent anyone downstream from changing the license, nor from changing the license of a derivative - unlike a copyleft license such as the GPL. They can essentially license their fork how they like.

If they relicense it under CC BY-NC, you're not allowed to sell it because of the NonCommercial clause in BY-NC. However, that's not a free license.

If they've relicensed it under a free license (of which there's a list on the FSF website), then *by definition* this allows you to redistribute their work and sell it on.

Keep in mind, however, that if they're providing the same package for free, you're not going to get many customers simply because it's cheaper elsewhere.

Comment: So they are allowed to take my work under the MIT License and apply a license of their choosing to it?

Comment: @Evorlor yes - MIT doesn't prevent that. A copyleft license would.

Comment: CC-BY-NC would be a very strange license for software though, I doubt much software is distributed under that

Comment: @Martijn Indeed, the CC website rather explicitly says something along the lines of "CC licenses are not intended for software, please don't use them for such, use one of these instead"

Comment: The CC-BY-NC is a share alike license. You can't remove the NC part of the license by making a derivative. Look up the license terms.

Comment: @prosfilaes Actually, there's no SA clause in BY-NC, so it's not share alike and you can relicense.

Comment: @ArtOfCode The short form says "No additional restrictions — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits." The legal terms says "You may not offer or impose any additional or different terms or conditions on, or apply any Effective Technological Measures to, the Licensed Material if doing so restricts exercise of the Licensed Rights by any recipient of the Licensed Material." I don't know where you're getting this "you can relicense" from.

Comment: @prosfilaes - from the fact that there's no share-alike requirement. With CC licenses, if there's no -SA in the name, you **can** relicense distributions. The SA version of BY-NC would be BY-NC-SA.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Read the license, don't just say "there's no SA", therefore I can do whatever I want.

Comment: @prosfilaes I *have* read the license. Several times. "You may not offer or impose any additional or different terms or conditions on, or apply any Effective Technological Measures to, the Licensed Material if doing so restricts exercise of the Licensed Rights by any recipient of the Licensed Material" was your quote; relicensing doesn't prevent exercise of the rights as long as the new license is compatible in this respect. It may even grant further rights.

Comment: @ArtOfCode You are correct, it's not SA. I see the difference there. I stand by the conclusion that a license to "reproduce and Share the Licensed Material, in whole or in part, for NonCommercial purposes only; and     produce, reproduce, and Share Adapted Material for NonCommercial purposes only." does not give you the right to relicense an Adapted work and then sell it, any more then you can relicense an Adapted work of a CC-BY work and then fail to provide credit.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Try to think of it this way: If what you are proposing were indeed possible, what difference would there be between CC-BY or CC-BY-NC? Or even between CC-BY and putting absolutely no restriction on it. Someone who licensed you the work under CC-BY-NC never gave you the right to use it non-commercially. While relicensing is indeed allowed, you can only relicense to *stricter* terms, not weaker.

Comment: This has turned into a prolonged argument, something that is discouraged. I think this comment thread merits [its own question](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/can-i-re-license-my-adaptation-of-cc-by-nc-materials-under-commercial-terms).  I look forward to seeing well thought-out interpretations arguing either position.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, *provided* they license their improvements under MIT or another free/libre license.

Please note that MIT (Expat) is a *permissive* license, so the fork *may* no longer be free/libre software - the improvements may even be proprietary (ARR) - in that case, the other party will be able to sell the improved version, but you will *not* have that option (but you can still sell the your original version).

If you use a *Copyleft* license (e.g. GPLv3) instead of MIT/Expat, they can't do this.  Then any improvements to your program must be licensed under the same license.

However, if the improvements have a free/libre license, you're allowed to sell free software, even if you don't hold the full copyright (or *any* copyright).

Also see: http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.en.html (while this is from the FSF, it also applies to permissive licenses such as MIT (Expat)).